# Jquery Datatable not showing correct number of rows as per dropdown entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have ajax call which returns table. In success method I use `$("#tableID").dataTable();` It although shows paging and number of rows in dropdown, but it is just displaying all rows instead of only number of rows as selected in dropdown. In other words number of rows to be shown is not working.

I tried using below in `$(document).ready` but it also didn't work
   `$("#tbAccount").dataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 10
            });`

My code is below:

```
  function ShowNodeDetails(levelId, parentGroupID) {
        $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "AccountsView.aspx/GetNodeDetails",
                            data: "{'levelID':'" + levelId + "','ParentGroupId':'" + parentGroupID + "'}",
                            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: true,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (msg) {

                                $("#dvAccountDetails").empty();
                                $("#dvAccountDetails").append(msg.d);
                                $("#tbAccount").dataTable(
                                {
                                    "iDisplayLength": 10
                                });
                            }
                        });

    }
```

Am using jquery, javascript and ajax from last 5 days only. So maybe, I lack maybe debugging skills in the same.

Comment: You're using a server-side datasource, so your `GetNodeDetails` method needs to take care of the paging.  Is it?

Comment: Yeah, I am using server side. But is data not always fetched from server side! I am getting data but is there way I can implement pager on that using datatable of jquery

Comment: You need to handle the paging in the server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving these options:
Destroy:  Will recreate the datatable if it already exists.
Searching: Can be set to True or False.
Ordering: For sorted or unsorted list.
LengthMenu: Custom pager lengths per table

```
$('#tbAccount').dataTable( {
     destroy: true,
     searching: true,
     ordering:  true,
     lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ]                                                    
});
```